# how did my certificate got to /lib/security/cacerts?

Tags: java, security

a couple of days ago I was creating a self-signed certificate using the jdk's keytool and I specified a keystore file (a file named my.jks) and now that I was checking (and realizing) that there is a default certificates store in  /lib/security/cacerts I can see that the self-signed certificate that I created has gone there too. Is this the expected behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A self-signed certificate is definitely not supposed to be stored in cacerts unless you ask for it (that is, unless you put it there). The cacerts file is supposed to contain root certificates from trusted CA's. It is a part of the jdk distribution and as such is maintained by Oracle.
If you want the jdk to trust your newly created certificate there is two ways:
1. You may put it into cacerts
2. You may create a different keystore and set this as the truststore when starting java
Could it be that you was following some instructions that told you to store the certificate in cacerts?